# How can I open Apple Reminders app programmatically?

Tags: ios

Is there a way to open the Apple Reminders app programmatically?

Answer (score 4):

I have tried in Swift 5+ and iOS 13, you need to use the following url scheme.(Earlier `x-apple-reminder://` was working but now it isn't)

`x-apple-reminderkit://`

```
if let url = URL(string: "x-apple-reminderkit://"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:]) { (isDone) in
            
        }
    }
```

It will open the iOS Reminder App from your application.

Hope it may be helpful to other.

Comment: This worked — is there an option to do so with the `Details` pane open and a reminder pre-filled for a specified time?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
let url = URL(string: "x-apple-reminder://")
    UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:]) { (finish) in

}
```

**Reference for all apple apps scheme :** 
https://ios.gadgethacks.com/news/always-updated-list-ios-app-url-scheme-names-0184033/

Comment: Will this pass App Store Review? I didn't see this URL on Apple's list of public schemes

Answer (score -1):

and if you use x-apple-reminderkit://today, you can open the Today "view" in Reminders.

Still trying to figure out how to open a specific list or the Flagged view, though.

Comment: As of iOS 16 (did not test on previous versions), this does not work. It opens the Reminders app but not the Today view.